# How to compile clojure modules that are not under "src" in a lein project

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I built my project using lein new app hello, so I have this structure

```
.
└── src
    └── hello
        └── core.clj
└── project.clj
└── test
└── ..
```

I want to add another helper module to my project such that I can use the code in both the tests and the src modules as I wanted it decoupled from the src directory.

So I added a helpers module

```
.
└── src
    └── hello
        └── core.clj
└── project.clj
└── test
└── helpers
    └──hello
         └── helpers.clj
```

How can I change my project.clj file to make `lein run` compile. `lein run` does not compile and throws the following error when I try to require the helpers namespace.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   hello.helpers, compiling:(hello/core.clj:7:3)

My project.clj file looks like the default one :

```
(defproject hello "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "FIXME: write description"
  :url "http://example.com/FIXME"
  :license {:name "Eclipse Public License"
            :url "http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html"}
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.8.0"]]
  :main ^:skip-aot hello.core
  :target-path "target/%s"
  :profiles {:uberjar {:aot :all}})
```

However in the IDE(IntelliJ) it works fine in the REPL, without throwing the class not found exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add

```
:source-paths ["src" "helpers"]
```

to your `project.clj` file.

Comment: using `(:require [hello.helpers :as h])` is the correct way to require . I was just testing using `(hello.helpers/test)` and that did not work